# Python interpreter up-arrow to complete to most recent instance in history

Tags: python

Within the python interpreter, I want to be able to use the up arrow to complete a partial from history. For example, if I have entered the following in to the interpreter:

```
A = 'a really long string'
B = 3
C = more
...
A = '
```

And then press the up-arrow, I want to just search back through the commands in the history that start

```
A = '
```

EDIT:

As pointed out below, `CTRL+R` will do the trick.

Comment: did you try `CTRL+R` and  `A = `?, I know this is not uparrow but yoiu can use it

Comment: In the Python shell `Alt-P` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

In IDLE go to Option -> Configure IDLE -> Keys -> (find in the list) History-previous -> Get New Keys for Selection -> (find in the list, somewhere nearrer to bottom) Up key

Ok apply, whatever works for you.

A good idea would be to save the new keyset as a Custom Key Set so you can return to the IDLE Classic Key Set anytime later.

Comment: Is there a way to this within the python interpreter?

Comment: @jmlarson: [Read This](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interactive.html#key-bindings) 

If you're stuck in a terminal version and don't have the GUI (which I thought you were referring to as idle, silly me) you can edit `~\.idlerc` or by  doing : 

`import rlcompleter, readline
readline.parse_and_bind('history_previous: Up')` 

in a startup script ( file identified by PYTHONSTARTUP env. variable). You can additionally add an export statement in .bashrc that will set the same  PYTHONSTARTUP variable everytime.

Comment: Yes, I have a .pystartup file that is loaded when I open the interpreter. And I have included your binding of history_previous to Up, but it still doesn't work. If I enter H =1 (enter) A = 1 (enter) H = (up arrow), then I get the previous history entry, not the completion of H =.

Comment: @jmlarson: sry, the correct syntax would be `history-previous: Up Arrow`. Iti's also not a "history completion" as much as just "history". That is when you have an empty line and press up arrow you'll get the previous command. Not sure if it'll work if you do H= [up arrow]. Hope it works, otherwise that's pretty much all I got untill I log into ubuntu and try it for myself.